# is it posssible to share a local directory with an emulated device on android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Is it possible to share a directory with a emulated device in android studio?

I want to be able to access a local directory from device's file manager (so it is available to all apps), and such that changes are detected immediately.

I just started with android studio, I searched but i could only find how to copy files...

BTW, I'm on ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could push the directory using adb or Android Studio.  That's generally not a feature an emulator like this would have, as its not a realistic setup on a phone.

A workaround would be to setup a file watcher on your local directory and perform a push when a file is changed.